# reactjs: material ui: how to align two items to the two ends

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code in reactjs using material ui theme

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root2: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper2: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  }
})

<div className={classes.root2}>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper2}>
       <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item>
            <h3>Instructions</h3>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <IconButton>
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

What i want is

[image]

I saw an example at https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/#flex-grow

[image]

which uses the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

export default function FlexGrow() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
        <Box p={1} flexGrow={1} bgcolor="grey.300">
          Item 1
        </Box>
        <Box p={1} bgcolor="grey.300">
          Item 2
        </Box>
        <Box p={1} bgcolor="grey.300">
          Item 3
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am new to material ui. Here the example uses Box instead of Grid.

So which is the best way to handle this

I am used to bootstrap 4: IN bootstrap4 i can do this same thing using

[image]

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">...</div>
```

How to do something like this in material UI

Comment: Use flexbox on the parent container and add properties as `display: flex;`, `justify-content: space-between`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `justify="space-between"` to `Grid` container component will solve your issue.

Please refer [this](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive).

```
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper2}>
       <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="space-between">
          <Grid item>
            <h3>Instructions</h3>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <IconButton>
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: unfortunately there is no full code shown here. https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive. rest everywhere for each example the full code is shown